# cannot find symbol method with() using picasso library android

Tags: android, image, picasso

i'm getting one issue in android app, I am trying to check already existing app, the app contains

```
 implementation('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
```

picasso library and

using that library in a class, here is the code

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    Picasso.with().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_pic).into(imageView);
```

here is the error, `Error:(49, 20) error: cannot find symbol method with()`

and my android studio version is 3.0 RC1, is this is an issue ?

Comment: How can I replace by Picasso.with(MainActivity.this) with Get() method?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It looks like in the latest Picasso Snapshot that you are using the method `with` hast been renamed to `get` see related commit here: https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae

**so replace `with()` with `get()` and should work.**

Since you are using a not yet officially released version, there are no release notes yet, and surprizes like that can happen ;-)

BTW: It seems to be a good name change to me, since a method named "with" but without parameter was a bit weird :-P

Comment: Do you know where `Picasso` gets the context from with the new method? It use to be `with(context)` and now it's `get()`, without passing context?

Comment: Maybe the context of the image view it is loading the image in.

Comment: @ClassA it uses the `getContext()` from Android's `ContentProvider`, see `PicassoProvider.java`

Comment: I am not able to find either `get()` or `with()`. Does it have something to do with Proguard?

Comment: Picasso.get() is should be work
Picasso.with(context) is Deprecated

Answer (score 42):

Use `get()`  Instead of `with()` it will work

```
Picasso.get().load("image_URL").into(imageView);
```

[`with()` hast been renamed to `get()`](https://github.com/square/picasso/commit/e7e919232fe2b15772a7fcd9e15ead2304c66fae)

Comment: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.3-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Umm.. so you suggest to downgrade the picasso version, but what if the user wants to actually use the upcoming 3.x version already?

Comment: @donfuxx just updating ans

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/364 recommends to update to 3.0.0-SNAPHOT.

Answer (score 21):

We have to replace `with()` with `get()` and **very important, now the context is not necessary for this method.**

```
 Picasso.get().load(url).into(view);
```

Add into the `build.gradle` file the dependency described into the documentation:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

[**Picasso documentation.**](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 7):

In the latest **Picasso** library, they renamed ***with()*** into ***get()***

So, instead of using

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_pic).into(imageView);
```

Use below line

```
Picasso.get().load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_pic).into(imageView);
```

Comment: What happened to passing the context? Why was it not required anymore?

Answer (score 7):

you need change method with() for get()

example:

before:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(listaConductores.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).into(holder.imageId);
```

after:

`Picasso.get().load(listaConductores.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).into(holder.imageId);`

my dependencie:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Picasso.with(context).load("imageUrl").into(imageView);

replace it with this below code.

Picasso.get().load("imageUrl").into(imageView);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of with() :

```
Picasso.with().load(listdata.getImageurl()).into(img);
```

Use get() :

```
Picasso.get().load(listdata.getImageurl()).into(img);
```

And into the `build.gradle` add this :

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

And this work for me...

Comment: Wrong. v2.4.0 still uses `Picasso.with()`.

Answer (score 1):

*** Try this line of code, if you're using Picasso library v.2.5.2 ***

`Picasso.with(context).load("imageUrl").into(imageView);`

Add this into your build.gradle file inside dependecies

`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

*** Try this line of code, if you're using older version for example v.2.4.0***

`Picasso.get(context).load("imageUrl").into(imageView);`

Add this into your build.gradle file inside dependecies

`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("image_URL").into(imageView);
```

*Change this Code into ..*

```
Picasso.get().load("image_URL").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

add this dependency to your build.gradel file and sync.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Replace with(context) to get()

also add to Gradle

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: Why does this work?  What happened to the context?  Why did they make such a big change (ie, breaking all old code)?

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade to Picasso library v.2.5.2 to avoid code debugging which worked faster and easier.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'---> downgraded version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using :-
Picasso.get().load("image_URL").into(imageView);

u can use
Picasso.with(Context).load("image_URL").into(imageView);