# Image url not loading in picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I am trying to load image URL using Picasso but it is showing white screen I have checked on the browser URL is working below my code which I have implemented

```
  Picasso.get().load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lxgp2xj8wtv3zk/10762650.jpg?dl=0qaC8sFGR/tA4zUizSJLwx+oamRxyLDuPAPc/4Un7thhg2evDYq0Sf/9k=FLMf").into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Did you add   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in manifest?

Comment: It's a permission issue. When I tried to view the image, It requested that I log into DropBox

Comment: Which version of Picasso are you using?

Comment: but what is your suggestion I have open permission to all

Comment: I am using Picasso version 2.71828

Comment: I can view it in browser.

Comment: I have added internet permission already

Comment: what is your suggestion guys

Comment: Your image url have access rights issues, just try opening that link on browser.

Comment: try another img url, or try another library. may be its problem related to picasso version.

Comment: on the browser it is showing

Comment: guys what is your suggestion I have created json api and I want to add my image inside json structure but I have used shared image using dropbox

Comment: please use universal image loader to find the exact reason for not showing the image. In universal image loader we will get error logs.**Note : To check the error log at testing time, use Universal Image Loader** [library link is here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52620522/7319704

Comment: The URL does not give an image, it gives an HTML page

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the image url. It works while using this url

```
Picasso.get().load("https://wpexpert.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/404.png").into(iv);
```

Also you can see that Picasso logs by using this above the above code like this

```
Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true);
Picasso.get().load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lxgp2xj8wtv3zk/10762650.jpg?dl=0qaC8sFGR/tA4zUizSJLwx+oamRxyLDuPAPc/4Un7thhg2evDYq0Sf/9k=FLMf").into(iv);
```

So when we use your dropbox url Picasso gives error in logcat, so it is the problem with your url.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a image url, it return a html page, so that's why you can't use picasso to load it. This is the image link of yours

https://uc52595a7f87e89649b8eba6841a.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/AAOV4bUqGNXWc8uhjaUYwa4qd7wOQoFd0n3knAOExhdSld6_X1YaUoXMWjFu67MbeH51odoGBKvInbnYW7radDMrFUfk9aPeVKP7z44inNgvzPF0C8deonSqHrAHGzXRPHyu_2h6cuPGFnwxTK3-bDBGVBC6MO-0hAe1Dkpw-lAONLGMvxW-vHzdIqnR056x55yLAce5dWpQ7PkzLlKEMqiEjytGjwRuoi0roscHwS5d-g/p.jpeg?size=1600x1200&size_mode=3

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be set by Dropbox itself. When I tried to load image from dropbox url

I am getting HTTP 504 error. It's a timeout error.
But dropbox hadle this to control server load.

You can get more detailed info from [here.](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Error-messages/Error-504-when-trying-to-access-Dropbox/m-p/186334#M9855)

I guess you can't show images from dropbox shared link.

One the other hand, Universal Image Loader will give

> DECODING_ERROR

while loading from dropbox url.

So, better avoid dropbox urls.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the image file itself and don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to manifest.`

```
Picasso.get().load("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lxgp2xj8wtv3zk/10762650.jpg").into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: what is your suggestion in this case

Comment: Removing all the extra details after .jpg on the image link or using a different url.

Comment: what is your suggestion I have created json api and I want to add my image inside json structure but I have used shared image using dropbox as you can use it is not working

Comment: Try this url https://www.instituteofphotography.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/dummy-profile-pic-300x300.jpg

Comment: Exactly what I'm telling you. The problem is dropbox. Use another service like Flickr or upload your files to another server